# Any reason this ng-message doesn't work?

Tags: angularjs

i have this code, im not sure way my ng-massage dosent pop up... it use to work before i changed some css and html..

before:

```
<li>
    <p flex style="margin-right: 14px;" class="wm-phone" >
    <label >Phone:</label>
    <input style="  width: 92%;" 
           name="phone_number"
           ng-click="bookingPage.phone_number"
           placeholder='edit' 
           onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" 
           ng-model="bookingPage.phone_number" 
           type="number"         
           ng-minlength="6" 
           class="wm-edit wm-phone-hide-spin-button"/> 
     </p>
     <div ng-messages="BookingPageEditForm.phone_number.$error" 
     style="color:maroon;margin-left: 17px;">
        <div ng-message="number">Not a valid number</div>
    </div>
</li>
```

after:

```
<li >
<div  style="margin-right: 14px;" class="wm-phone" layout="row" layout-md="column" layout-sm="column">
    <div ><label >Phone:</label></div>
    <div > <input  
            name="phone_number"
            ng-click="bookingPage.phone_number"
            placeholder='edit' 
            onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" 
            ng-model="bookingPage.phone_number" 
            type="number"         
            ng-minlength="6" 
            class="wm-edit wm-phone-hide-spin-button"/></div> 
</div>
<div ng-messages="BookingPageEditForm.phone_number.$error" 
     style="color:maroon;margin-left: 17px;">
    <div ng-message="number">Not a valid number</div>
</div>
</li>
```

i tried to change it back but now they both don't work... any help would be welcome..

Comment: problem solved, it was my mistake, needed to put it all inside a form and accidentally deleted it...

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, it was my mistake, needed to put it all inside a form and accidentally deleted it.

```
<form method="post" 
      name="BookingForm" 
      style="margin-bottom: 67px;"
      ng-submit="settingSet()">
<li >
<div  style="margin-right: 14px;" class="wm-phone" layout="row" layout-md="column" layout-sm="column">
    <div ><label >Phone:</label></div>
    <div > <input  
            name="phone_number"
            ng-click="bookingPage.phone_number"
            placeholder='edit' 
            onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" 
            ng-model="bookingPage.phone_number" 
            type="number"         
            ng-minlength="6" 
            class="wm-edit wm-phone-hide-spin-button"/></div> 
</div>
<div ng-messages="BookingPageEditForm.phone_number.$error" 
     style="color:maroon;margin-left: 17px;">
    <div ng-message="number">Not a valid number</div>
</div>
</li>

</form>
```